# MvvmCross 6 RecyclerView multiple buttons item binding

Tags: xamarin, android-recyclerview, mvvmcross

I'm really new in Xamarin & more in MvvmCross. For the moment, I succeeded doing some basic stuff.

But now, I'm facing a simple problem (for me). I got an `MvxRecyclerView`. Each of its items has 2 buttons. How can I bind them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your ViewModels:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.MyItems.Add(new MyItemViewModel());
        this.MyItems.Add(new MyItemViewModel());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> MyItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel>();
}

public class MyItemViewModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public MyItemViewModel()
     {
          // Initialize your commands
     }

     public ICommand MyCommand1 { get; set; }

     public ICommand MyCommand2 { get; set; }
}
```

In your view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.recyclerview.MvxRecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_test"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyItems" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your item view `item_test.axml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My button 1"
        local:MvxBind="Click MyCommand1" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My button 2"
        local:MvxBind="Click MyCommand2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

HIH